# On h:commandLink Ajax Success/Failure open Modal Dialog

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have implemented an action bar with different command links firing ajax calls. My backing bean handles those actions.

```
<a4j:commandLink value="Save" action="#{actionHandler.perform('save')}" execute="@form"
oncomplete="" onerror="">
</a4j:commandLink>
```

OR

```
<h:commandLink value="Save">
  <f:ajax execute="@form" actionListener="#{actionHandler.perform('save')}"
</h:commandLink>
```

What i want to achieve is that for every commandlink in my action bar when ajax call has success/failure then show a modal dialog alongth with current performed action specific information like header, message, redirect URL etc. In other request/response based framework we normally return a JSON respone and act accordingly. But i dont know how can we achieve this here. I looked at Richfaces(the framework in use) rich:popupPanel but could not find any way to pass parameters to popup. Any suggesstion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a4j:commandLink` (or `a4j:commandButton`). Example (from RichFaces 4.3 project):

```
<a4j:commandLink action="#{bean.setupTransactionDetails}"
    event="onclick" render="transactionDetails"
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('transactionDetails')}.show()"
    styleClass="richLink">
    <h:outputText value="#{res.transactionType}" />
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{res.transactionId}"
        target="#{bean.transactionId}" />
</a4j:commandLink>
```

Where #res.transactionId is parameter, transactionDetails is name of popup.